# How to have focus only on loading form while an event is occurring

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, focus, loading

i would like to know how can i get focus on my loading form when an event is fired. As soon as when i press the button **my loading screen pops up and after couple of seconds it loosing focus**.. which mean, i am able to click my main form, especially all my columns cells and stuffs How can i get rid of this??

Codes:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool done = false;
        //thread pool should be used under  a seperate manager so that UI dont get affected 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
        {
            using (var splashForm = new Form4())
            {
                splashForm.Show();
                while (!done)
                    Application.DoEvents();
                splashForm.Close();
            }
        });
        move(); // move files
        Datagrid_bind();
        done = true;

    }
```

Comment: try using async/await features

Comment: try set `this.Enabled = false` before queuing and set `this.Enabled  = true` after you set `done = true`, you can also hide and show background form.

Comment: @dotctor.. I tried using this.. but its givng me error.. http://pastie.org/9784849#3-4,7,16,25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the user not to be able to click on your main form while it's loading the data. If that's the case, you can simply hide your form while it loads:

```
myMainForm.Hide();
```

When it finishes loading, you call Show again:

```
myMainForm.Show();
```

Comment: I know this will work... but i dont want to use this??

Comment: What about disabling it?

Comment: how it didn't work? If you requires such specific solution, you should provide us with a specific question as well; We're not supposed to tell you neither to hide it or disable it. There's not much I can suggest you then unless you provide us with more details on what you're doing, what you want to accomplish and how it can and can't be done.